# Splitting a subdirectory with submodules into a separate git repository

Tags: git, git-filter-branch

As a subset of the question [detach-subdirectory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359424/detach-subdirectory-into-separate-git-repository) already made before and considering the fact that even though a lot of questions were made about the process of splitting and merging git repositories, I couldn't find one that touches the subject of splitting when submodules are present.

So in the following scenario:

```
.git/
.gitmodules
folder/
    data/
    content/
        other_data/
        submoduleA/
        submoduleB/
```

I would like to get two repositories with the following structure:

```
.git/
data/
```

and

```
.git/
.gitmodules
content/
    other_data/
    submoduleA/
    submoduleB/
```

The first case is not a problem and can be solved easily with the method described in [detach-subdirectory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359424/detach-subdirectory-into-separate-git-repository).

The second not so much. The existence of submodules and the fact that .gitmodules contains the full path for `folder/content/submoduleA` and `folder/content/submoduleB` causes part of the history to be inconsistent since .gitmodules refers to a nonexistent directory structure (once filter-branch is used).

So I would like to know if there is a way to do this without causing inconsistent history.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect (not tested) that a second `git filter-branch` would have the opportunity to modify the `.gitmodules` content for each commits of the new repo.

But actually a [**`git submodule split`** command was in discussion early 2009](http://kerneltrap.org/mailarchive/git/2009/2/14/5157494).

> Proposed usage:

```
git submodule split [--url submodule_repo_url] submodule_dir \
    [alternate_dir...]
```

> Replace `submodule_dir` with a newly-created submodule, keeping all the history of `submodule_dir`.
>   This command also rewrites each commit in the current repository's history to include the correct revision of `sumodule_dir` and the appropriate `.gitmodules` entries.

However, I don't see it in the [latest what's cooking](http://article.gmane.org/gmane.comp.version-control.git/152607).
The script in the proposed patch can give you an idea of the kind of tree rewriting necessary to update the `.gitmodules` file though.

Comment: Using a second git filter-branch command I was able to rewrite .gitmodules with a sed command, however the actual submodule folders are still left untouched (both with index-filter and tree-filter). Only subdirectory-filter was able to change them but then .gitmodules is removed.
The git submodule split command seems to do exactly what I intend, but reading the thread I got the impression that it has a few problems so I don't feel comfortable using it.

Comment: @Unode: I understand. I don't think this particular patch is in active development right now.

Answer (score 6):

I had the exact same problem as Unode and managed to resolve it with the following procedure:

```
git clone git@github.com:kdeldycke/kev-code.git
cd kev-code
git filter-branch --tree-filter "test -f ./.gitmodules && mv ./.gitmodules ./cool-cavemen/gitmodules || echo 'No .gitmodules file found'" -- --all
git filter-branch --force --prune-empty --subdirectory-filter cool-cavemen --tag-name-filter cat -- --all init..HEAD
git filter-branch --force --tree-filter "test -f ./gitmodules && mv ./gitmodules ./.gitmodules || echo 'No gitmodules file found'" -- --all
git filter-branch --force --tree-filter "test -f ./.gitmodules && sed -i 's/cool-cavemen\///g' ./.gitmodules || echo 'No .gitmodules file found'" -- --all
git remote rm origin
rm -rf .git/refs/original/
git reflog expire --all
git gc --aggressive --prune
git remote add origin git@github.com:kdeldycke/cool-cavemen.git
git push -u origin master --force --tags
```

As you see, the trick is to temporarily rename the `.gitmodules` file and use `sed` to rewrite its content. You can get all details and the [context of this procedure on my blog](http://kevin.deldycke.com/2011/02/moving-git-subtree-repository/comment-page-1/#comment-8554).

Comment: You may want to include `--tag-name-filter cat` option in all filter-branch commands to preserve tags after filtering.

Comment: Thanks for documenting this. Two things I had to tweak to get this to work. First, I think you assume an initial commit tagged as `init` for the `init..HEAD` range. Second, I had to add `-e` to the sed command, i.e.: `sed -i -e 's/cool-cavemen\///g' ./.gitmodules`

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate on Kevin's answer: assuming that no submodules ever existed outside  `cool/cavemen` – the folder being detached (otherwise more elaborate editing of .gitmodules will be needed to remove those extra sections), this can be achieved *much* faster and in one step using an `index-filter`:

```
$ git filter-branch --subdirectory-filter cool/cavemen --index-filter $'
hash=$(git rev-parse --verify $GIT_COMMIT:.gitmodules 2>/dev/null) &&
 git update-index --add --cacheinfo 100644 $(git cat-file -p $hash |
 sed \'s/cool\\/cavemen\\///g\' | git hash-object -w --stdin) .gitmodules ||
true' --tag-name-filter cat --prune-empty -- --all
```

As an added benefit, if `cool/cavemen` did not exist in every revision or branch only those revisions or branches that did contain `cool/cavemen` will be looked at.

If this is the case you may want to run the following to remove unchanged references:

```
$ git for-each-ref --format='%(refname)' | 
 grep -vF "$(git for-each-ref --format='%(refname)' refs/original |
 sed 's/refs\/original\///g')" | xargs -n 1 git update-ref -d
```